# Keras: fix "IndexError: list index out of range" error when using model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm trying to build a Variational Autoencoder with several Conv2d layers that works with cifar-10.
It seems all right, but when I run the training I get this error:

```
Train on 50000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
  100/50000 [..............................] - ETA: 2:19

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-8-a9198aa155a7> in <module>()
      3         epochs=1,
      4         batch_size=batch_size,
----> 5         validation_data=(x_test, None))

20 frames

/tensorflow-2.0.0-rc2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _model_loss(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    164 
    165         if hasattr(loss_fn, 'reduction'):
--> 166           per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(targets[i], outs[i])
    167           weighted_losses = losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
    168               per_sample_losses,

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried to reset the kernel and I've also tried with both tensorflow 2.0 and 1.14.0 but nothing changes.
I'm a newbie to keras and tf, so I have probably made some mistakes.

Here's the architecture of my VAE:

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0],) + original_img_size)
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0],) + original_img_size)

latent_dim = 128
kernel_size = (4,4)
original_img_size = (32,32,3)

#Encoder
x_in = Input(shape=original_img_size)
x = x_in
x = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=2, padding='SAME', input_shape=original_img_size)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)
x = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=2, padding='SAME')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)
x = Conv2D(512, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=2, padding='SAME')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)
x = Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=2, padding='SAME')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = layers.ReLU()(x)

flat = Flatten()(x)
hidden = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat)

#mean and variance
z_mean = hidden
z_log_var = hidden

#Decoder
decoder_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))

decoder_fc3 = Dense(8*8*1024) (decoder_input)
decoder_fc3 = BatchNormalization()(decoder_fc3)
decoder_fc3 = Activation('relu')(decoder_fc3)

decoder_reshaped = layers.Reshape((8,8,1024))(decoder_fc3)

decoder_ConvT1 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='SAME', input_shape=(8,8,1024))(decoder_reshaped)
decoder_ConvT1 = BatchNormalization()(decoder_ConvT1)
decoder_ConvT1 = Activation('relu')(decoder_ConvT1)

decoder_ConvT2 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='SAME')(decoder_ConvT1)
decoder_ConvT2 = BatchNormalization()(decoder_ConvT2)
decoder_ConvT2 = Activation('relu')(decoder_ConvT2)

decoder_ConvT3 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(3,kernel_size=(4,4), strides=(1,1), padding='SAME')(decoder_ConvT2)

y = decoder_ConvT3

decoder = Model(decoder_input, y)

x_out = decoder(encoder(x_in))

vae = Model(x_in, x_out)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=vae_loss) #custom loss 
vae.fit(x_train,
        shuffle=True,
        epochs=1,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=(x_test, None))
```

Here's my custom loss function:

```
def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
  xent_loss = losses.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean)
  kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
  return xent_loss + kl_loss
```

As suggested by qmeeus I tried to add a target output, but now I get this error:

```
Train on 50000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
  100/50000 [..............................] - ETA: 12:33

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/tensorflow-2.0.0-rc2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     60                                                op_name, inputs, attrs,
---> 61                                                num_outputs)
     62   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: dense/Identity:0


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

_SymbolicException                        Traceback (most recent call last)

11 frames

/tensorflow-2.0.0-rc2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     73       raise core._SymbolicException(
     74           "Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic "
---> 75           "tensors, but found {}".format(keras_symbolic_tensors))
     76     raise e
     77   # pylint: enable=protected-access

_SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'dense/Identity:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=float32>]
```

If you need more details let me know.

Comment: What's probably wrong is your custom loss. Please provide that in the question.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error but with a normal supervised model (not AE). It might not be the problem in your case, but might be relevant to others with the same error: Make sure that your validation_data is a tuple.

Comment: I think OP provided an example, maybe you can show it works after you make validation_data a tuple? I think it would be something to learn for everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this instead:

```py
vae.fit(x_train, x_train
        shuffle=True,
        epochs=1,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=(x_test,x_test))
```

Keras is expecting a target output (for example `y_train` in supervised learning, `x_train` in autoencoders) that you did not provide. From the doc:

> You can either pass the name of an existing loss function, or pass a TensorFlow/Theano symbolic function that returns a scalar for each data-point and takes the following two arguments:
>
> ```
> y_true: True labels. TensorFlow/Theano tensor.
> y_pred: Predictions. TensorFlow/Theano tensor of the same shape as y_true.
> ```
>
> The actual optimized objective is the mean of the output array across all datapoints.

The way I usually do is simply to provide the same target as the input to the fit method, as shown in the code above...

[EDIT]:
The error comes from your definition of kld that uses methods from `tf.keras.backend`. I'm no expert in tensorflow 2 but this is definitely the reason of the error. Refer to [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae) to know how to build your loss.

Another workaround is to build a model with two outputs and create two loss functions, one for each output, eg

```py
model = Model(x_in, [hidden, y])
model.compile(loss=[custom_kld, binary_crossentropy], optimizer=optimizer)
```

Comment: Now I get this error ` _SymbolicException: Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'dense/Identity:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=float32>]`

Comment: This is related to something else that your original post. What is the full traceback?

Comment: I've just added it :)

Comment: Could you provide your imports as well? I'm trying to reproduce the error. From the error, I understand that you are using tensorflow 2.0, are you also using keras or only tf.keras? The error might be caused by mixing keras and tf.keras code, although it is difficult to know at this point...

Comment: Even with your imports i still get the same error. 
I'm running all the code on Google Colaboratory, with python 3.6. Here's the link to my notebook:
[link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lUIcxBDUE6WSCfksdkZnx4kih5LUi4fJ)

Comment: See my edit and in particular, the tutorial referenced

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was because of my Label Array.
I solved in this way:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
y_tr = to_categorical(y_tr)
y_te = to_categorical(y_te)
y_val = to_categorical(y_val)
```

So while my array looked like (there are 20 classes):

```
array(15)
```

After the function to_categorical() they looks like:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

So they have all 0 and 1 in the relative position (index) of the correct label